# store event return values in a list?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

i am new to events and delegates. I wonder if its possible to store the return values of an event in a list.

i have an event that looks like this:

```
public delegate CartItem AddItemToCart();
public event AddItemToCart OnCollect;
```

now i fire the OnCollect event everytime the user presses a button. I need to store all the returning CartItems of the methods that subscribed to OnCollect in a list. My approach:

```
List<CartItem> items = new List<CartItem> ();
itmes.Add(OnCollect());
```

however (kind of expected) this doesn't work. So How can i read out the return values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but it's a little ugly. You can use [`Delegate.GetInvocationList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.delegate.getinvocationlist?view=netstandard-1.6#System_Delegate_GetInvocationList) to retrieve the individual delegates, each of which will be of the same delegate type as the combined one. So for example:

```
List<CartItem> items = new List<CartItem>();
foreach (AddItemToCart individual in OnCollect.GetInvocationList())
{
    items.Add(individual.Invoke());
}
```

Or I guess you could use LINQ:

```
List<CartItem> items = OnCollect
    .GetInvocationList()
    .Cast<AddItemCart>()
    .Select(d => d.Invoke())
    .ToList();
```

Note that this will create a new list each time, but with one element for each subscribed handler. If you need to amalgamate all the items from executing this multiple times, you'll need a `List<CartItem>` *field* (e.g. `allItems`), and then you can call `allItems.AddRange(items)`.

Comment: This works well even though I am not exactly sure what's going on there. I will do some reseach for that. Thank's a lot your solution

Comment: @Mycom: Basically if there's more than one subscribed method, this will go through all those methods in order. Looking through your question again, it's not really clear whether you were talking about multiple subscribed delegates, or multiple event invocations.